# WhatsApp Web "Next chat" hotkey collision with Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, whatsapp

I use WhatsApp Web on Chrome, and I enjoy the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> hotkey that goes to the next chat. I use it a lot.

I just upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. I noticed that now when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> it opens a Windows UI for switching between windows. This overrides the WhatsApp functionality, and now I can't use that.

I'm confused. Isn't Windows 10 a very popular operating system? Does this mean that all Windows 10 users can't use this feature? Is there a way for me to work around this problem?

Comment: I added Chrome to the question text. I use a US keyboard layout and my Windows is in US English. I don't think the brand of the keyboard matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found some new WhatsApp Web keyboard shortcuts, which
include the missing "Next chat" shortcut.
I have not been able to test all of them, but most seem to work.

- **Ctrl + Alt+ N**: Start new chat
- **Ctrl + Alt+ Shift + ]**: Next chat
- **Ctrl + Alt+ Shift + [**: Previous chat
- **Ctrl + Alt+ E**: Archive chat
- **Ctrl + Alt+ Shift + M**: Mute chat
- **Ctrl + Alt+ Backspace**: Delete chat
- **Ctrl + Alt+ Shift + N**: Create new group
- **Ctrl + Alt+ P**: Open profile status

Combinations of 4 keys are awkward, but some AHK magic could help
(as long as the chosen shortcuts don't conflict with Windows)..

Source :
[Best WhatsApp Web tips and tricks you can use](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/whatsapp-web-tips-and-tricks).

---

(*Old answer which does not work*:)

The idea in the following answer is to intercept the
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>
key-combination and send it to the Chrome window, meaning that it
will not pass through Windows.

The weakness in my answer is that I have no way to test it,
as I don't use WhatsApp Web or any other application that
uses this combination. So this answer is untested.

I'm using the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will intercept this key-combination when Chrome
is the active window, and will send the keys to Chrome,
thus bypassing Windows:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe chrome.exe
^!Tab::SendPlay, ^!{Tab}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: I'm a longtime AHK user, and I also tried to cobble together an AHK solution. I tried yours but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: @RamRachum: I added a new solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use the [WhatsApp Windows desktop client](https://www.whatsapp.com/download)

that have <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> as a shortcut for Next chat

you can use [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys/releases/) to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to anything not used (the new shortcut it may not work, but the old one will not work)

and you can use <kbd>Ctrl(right)</kbd>+<kbd>alt(right)</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> if you need it

Comment: Indeed I don't want to use the desktop client. I installed PowerToys now and I see the dialog for remapping a shortcut key, but I'm not sure what you want me to configure there. Can you be really specific?